# RSpec should receive instance object of class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Tell me please how to check if returned object in should_receive is an instance of ClassName.

```
Messaging.should_receive(:send_text).with(:foo, :bar, object)
```

Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it receive an instance of an specific class, then can use `instance_of`:

```
Messaging.should_receive(:send_text).with(:foo, :bar, instance_of(ClassName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is:
Messaging.should_receive(:send_text).with(:foo, :bar, kind_of(ClassName))

**EDIT:** Proper answer is:

```
Messaging.should_receive(:send_text).with(:foo, :bar, instance_of(ClassName))
```

Thanks to K M Rakibul Islam

Comment: You use `kind_of` for an object with a given module in its ancestors list. But, your question says, you want to do it for a class, then you should use `instance_of` as shown in my answer. For reference: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments